# SAS indirect macro processing

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a question on an exam paper which asks what is read in the SAS log

```
%let test=one;
%let one=two;
%let two=three;
%let three=last;

%put what displays is &&&&&test;
```

I was very surprised to find the answer was:  **two** as I would have thought that this reference would fully resolve to **last**.  SAS also agrees with the answer to be **two**.

Can anyone please explain how SAS arrives at the answer **two** as all theory notes I have read suggests that the macro processor should do the following

- scan1 &&&&&test - > &&&&test ( i.e && resolves to & and tells  processor to continue to scan from  right to left)
- scan2  &&&&test - >   &&&one
- scan3    &&&one - >    &&two
- scan4    &&two - >     &three
- scan5    &three - >       last

Answer (score 6):

Using the symbolgen option can help see what is happening in the log:

```
1    options symbolgen;

2    %let test=one;
3    %let one=two;
4    %let two=three;
5    %let three=last;
6
7    %put what displays is &&&&&test;
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable TEST resolves to one
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable ONE resolves to two
what displays is two
```

Going left to right and using brackets to show the tokens:

```
&&&&&test
(&&)(&&)(&test)
(&) (&) (one)
&&one
(&&)(one)
(&)(one)
&one
two
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However SAS Certification Prep guid explains this logic differently. They say the 1st scan resolves double ampersand to single ampersand, and then form then one scans for mright to left. your logic ( which is obviously correct) seems ot resolve form left rto right, and coninuesto resolve && to & .. strange. Still unclrea on how this works generally but thansk for your answer :-)

Comment: The [SAS Macro Language Reference](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/64754/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0vl7e3du5f7cjn1g4ajozqxe6b6.htm) says "It resolves the entire reference from left-to-right." I don't have the SAS Certification Prep Guide, but what you have quoted about right to left is new to me.

Comment: Look at the question this is dup'ed from; I go over the answer in a bit more detail there with some examples.  I would say that the prep guide is probably not wrong, but is probably worded confusingly - but also don't have the prep guide, so don't know for sure.